# Unable to connect to YARN webapp UI in CDH 5.11.2

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, apache-flink

This CDH cluster has been install for months, and be used to backup logs.

Today I try to run flink on yarn, and want to open yarn web ui to check  flink taskmanagers' state, i find 8088 port connect refuse.

````
```
 This site can’t be reached
 47.74.***.*** refused to connect.
 Search Google for *** *** 8088
 ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```
````

yarn port & address config as follows:

````
```
yarn.resourcemanager.address  8032
yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address  8030
yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address   8031
yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address  8033
yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address  8088
yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.https.address   8090
```
````

Even curl 'http://ip:8088' on the resource manager host, also get "connection refuse"

````
```
[root@bigdata-cdh02 ~]# netstat -tunlp|grep 8088
tcp        0      0 172.21.0.20:8088        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20606/java
````

```

BTW, I check yarn logs, it seems that yarn has successfully allocated resources for flink.